# Having difficulties in ending Michael Hartl's tutorial. Help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Following Michael Hartl's (amazing) [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/), on the [final section](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code%3afollowing_followers_actions), I get the following errors:

```
1) User micropost associations status feed should include the microposts of followed users
 Failure/Error: @user.feed.should include(mp3)
 expected [#<Micropost id: 2, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-12 21:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">, #<Micropost id: 1, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-11 22:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">] to include #<Micropost id: 3, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">
 Diff:
 @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 -#<Micropost id: 3, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">
 +[#<Micropost id: 2, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-12 21:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">, #<Micropost id: 1, content: "Foo bar", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-11 22:22:41", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:41">]
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:214

2) Micropost from_users_followed_by should include the followed user's microposts
 Failure/Error: Micropost.from_users_followed_by(@user).should include(@other_post)
 expected [#<Micropost id: 1, content: "foo", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46">] to include #<Micropost id: 2, content: "bar", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46">
 Diff:
 @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 -#<Micropost id: 2, content: "bar", user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46">
 +[#<Micropost id: 1, content: "foo", user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46", updated_at: "2011-01-12 22:22:46">]
 # ./spec/models/micropost_spec.rb:75

Finished in 9.18 seconds
153 examples, 2 failures
```

Seems like `mp3` is not included in the feed. Any ideas on how to fix it? Or where to look for possible errors in the code? I compared the files with [Hartl's original code](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app/); seems exact.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you have a problem setting relationships. Make sure your `follow!` method in your `User` model looks exactly like this

```
def follow!(followed)
  relationships.create!(:followed_id => followed.id)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem was missing { } on the MySQL snippet. Done with the tutorial! Thanks for your help.